# Chances of IDL in Image processing

Tags: idl-programming-language

I am a software engineer working in Medical Imaging.I have just started using the language IDL and i feel very comfortable with it.As a new member in this field with a language like IDL, i would like to know the chances of IDL in this field.Can any one help me?

Answer (score 0):

Well, so here is my biased opinion -> I'm heading the opposite way to you. I have used IDL (and before PV-Wave) on and off for ca 10 years (mostly MRI) and I'm now trying to part from it. Here is why. If you are proficient you can very quickly test something in an interactive / lightly scripted fashion. This is the typical use case of scientists; most have little CS education and are happy to grab any tool that seems to helpful. In fact, IDL is fairly good at dealing with largish arrays/images etc as you are likely to encounter in imaging.

However, it is not very pretty and coding gets increasingly awkward as your project size increases. If you are a software engineer, I suspect you'll hit the limits soon and will be cursing it no end. If you try to develop GUI code for people around you, you might be in for a rough ride. This is one of the main reasons I am moving over to Python + EPD with scipy and the likes. Also, binding to existing sophisticated image processing tools as you might need (registration, segmentation, etc) are not ideal.

A further complaint I have are the ongoing licensing costs. Even in an academic environment they are becoming prohibitive and I'd rather spend it on a Coop-student who could code for me than on ITT. A nice feature though is the ability to compile almost all IDL code into a sav file that others can use with a *free* IDL virtual machine.

Essentially, what it will come down to is how much your collaborators need you to use IDL. If it's fully your choice, I would look elsewhere. If there is a significant (and decent) code base, I would stay. The medical imaging plus astro community is dependent enough to keep this going for a while. If you do decide to hang on, I can highly recommend Dave Fanning's writings (his web page + his book + the google-group). He is somewhat of an icon in the idl community and certainly taught me things that were very useful. (Check out the mighty histogram function, I'm not kidding!)

Hope this works out for you.